# ExtJs 6 always show ext/modern/modern/src/layout/container/Column.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I want to try the hello world sample using Extjs 6.5.2.
When i try to run the following code

```
    var containerPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: 'app-div1',
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        title: 'Container Panel',
        layout: 'column',
        suspendLayout: true // Suspend automatic layouts while we do several different things that could trigger a layout on their own
    });

    containerPanel.add({
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Child Panel 1',
        height: 100,
        columnWidth: 0.5
    });

    containerPanel.add({
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Child Panel 2',
        height: 100,
        columnWidth: 0.5
    });
    containerPanel.suspendLayout = false;
    containerPanel.updateLayout();
```

the browser console is thrown error about

```
ext/modern/modern/src/layout/container/Column.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

even if i try to import the package in `app.js`

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    extend: 'MyApp.Application',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.*',
        'Ext.panel.Panel',
        'Ext.layout.container.Column'
    ]
});
```

I found that the `ext-6.5.2-trial.zip` have not included `container` folder in `\ext\modern\modern\src\layout`.

May i know if i miss any steps before i use `Ext.panel.Panel` component?
Thank you.

Comment: are you working for modern toolkit ?

Comment: This is not about your codes. The Error is `Column.js net::*ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND*`

Comment: @Njdhv, no, i want to try it on desktop browser.

Comment: @ksw87 please refer my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For classic you need to remove this 2 lines in your `app.js` `Ext.panel.Panel` and `Ext.layout.container.Column`. If you need you can requires in you `classic` views.

In [`modern`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.enums.Layout.html#property-column) toolkit there is no `column` layout but in [`classic`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.enums.Layout.html#property-column) there is present `column` layout **[Ext.layout.container.Column](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.layout.container.Column.html)**.

Please refer this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2afl)** this is working with `layout:column` property on `Ext.panel.Panel`.

```
var containerPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Container Panel',
    layout: 'column'
});

// Suspend automatic layouts while we do several different things that could trigger a layout on their own
containerPanel.suspendLayouts(true); //you can also use like this.
containerPanel.add({
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Child Panel 1',
    height: 100,
    columnWidth: 0.5
},{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Child Panel 2',
    height: 100,
    columnWidth: 0.5
});
containerPanel.resumeLayouts(true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Njdhv, I'm confused about `modern` and `classic` components before. Thank you for your help. :)